# Calculate how many items will be inserted into an array using formula

Tags: javascript

have this formula to insert 1's into an array of 0's

```
const arr = [0,0,0,0,0]
let pos = 2
const frequency = 2

while (pos < arr.length) {
  arr.splice(pos, 0, 1);
  pos += frequency;
}
```

so [0,0,0,0,0] becomes [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]

I want to determine how many items will be inserted before the while loop. In this case it will be 3.

I tried this...

```
const start = pos
const len = [...arr].length
const ans = Math.floor((len - start) / frequency)
```

But im not getting the correct answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you've did it right, you just need to use `frequency - 1` instead of `frequency`. This is because when you add a `1` the `1` is in front of you and you need to pass it, so when you pass the `frequency` decreases by one and then you pass `frequency - 1` zeros. Also you need to use `ceil` instead of `floor` as you may add a `1` and the array ends before the guessed number of zeros.

So the correct answer would be

```
const ans = Math.ceil((len - start) / (frequency - 1))
```